# Formik and yup validation is validating a non-required file input field

Tags: reactjs, validation, formik, yup

I have an input field (type file) that for some reason validates even though is not required.
With serial number i have a validation and it is not required and seems to work fine, no errors when submitting the empty field.. For the file input field I want only the input field to validate  when a file is being uploaded. What am i doing wrong?, i get this(see image below) when i click submit to test the validation.

here's my code:

```js
const validationSchema = Yup.object({
    title: Yup.string()
      .required("Title is required")
      .min(8, "Title must be at least 8 characters")
      .max(100, "Title cannot be more than 100 characters"),
    description: Yup.string()
      .required("Description is required")
      .min(8, "Description must be at least 8 characters")
      .max(100, "Description cannot be more than 100 characters"),
    serialNumber: Yup.string()
      .min(4, "Serial number must be at least 4 characters")
      .max(16, "Serial number cannot be more than 16 characters"),
    productStatus: Yup.number().required("A Status is required"),
    productType: Yup.number().required("A type is required"),
    img: Yup.mixed()
      .test(
        "fileSize",
        "File size too large, max file size is 1 Mb",
        (file) => file && file.size <= 1100000
      )
      .test(
        "fileType",
        "Incorrect file type",
        (file) =>
          file && ["image/png", "image/jpg", "image/jpeg"].includes(file.type)
      ),
  });
```

```
{formik.errors["img"] && formik.touched["img"] && (
                  <div style={{ color: "#B2484D", fontSize: ".8rem" }}>
                    {formik.errors.img}
                  </div>
                )}

           <Field name="img">
                  {() => {
                    // < - this will take fieldProps.. not used in this case, using formik instead
                    return (
                      <>
                        <input
                          onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
                          onChange={({ currentTarget }) => {
                            const file = currentTarget.files![0];
                            const reader = new FileReader();

                            if (file) {
                              reader.onloadend = () => {
                                setSelectedFile({
                                  file,
                                  previewURI: reader.result!,
                                });

                                setuploadbtnLabel(
                                  `You selected: ${file.name} - click again to change`
                                );
                              };
                              reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                              formik.setFieldValue("img", file);
                            }
                          }}
                          ref={inputFile}
                          type="file"
                          style={{ display: "none" }}
                          accept=".png,.jpg,.jpeg"
                        />
                      </>
                    );
                  }}
                </Field>
```

**EDIT**: here's a codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-chandrasekhar-34q1q?file=/src/App.js

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should try to add `notRequired()` or even `nullable()` to  the  `img` field on the YUP schema definition. From Yup [docs](https://github.com/jquense/yup#mixednotrequired-schema-alias-optional):

> Mark the schema as not required. Passing undefined (or null for nullable schema) as value will not fail validation.

**Edit:** Based on the sandbox you provided I been able to figure it out. The problem comes from the test you added. Basically the issue is that `file` is *undefined* when no file is selected so the validation always fails.

For example you could change this:

```
 .test(
    "fileSize",
    "File size too large, max file size is 1 Mb",
    (file) => file && file.size <= 1100000
  )
```

To this:

```
.test(
    "fileSize",
    "File size too large, max file size is 1 Mb",
    (file) => {
      if (file) {
        return file.size <= 1100000;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    }
  )
```

`notRequired()` or `nullable()` are not even necessary to make it work the way you expect to. Here is the link to the [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-yum-validation-input-file-xpd2y?file=/src/App.js) with this fix. If that works for you please do mark the answer as accepted.

Good luck!

Comment: Added `notRequired` and no success, then added both `nonRequired` and `nullable` but no luck with that either.

Comment: I forked this original [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/lkkjpr5r7) so you can try the behaviour of `notRequired()` [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-simple-upload-example-forked-9bd87?file=/index.js) Try changing line 76. I hope that works out for you!

Comment: thanks, but it still doesn't fix the issue.. it keeps preventing the form from getting submitted and throws the error if the file field is not touched or left empty.

Comment: I've added a link to a sandbox, hope that helps the troubleshooting

Comment: Hi! I added a working solution to the original answer, check it out!

Comment: I changed `(file) => file && file.size <= 1100000` to `(file) => file ? file.size <= 1100000 : true` and it seems to work. I will do more testing, THANK YOU!